# Dagger 2 cannot access Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, dagger-2, dagger

I'm trying to provide an instance of Retrofit to my Repository using Dagger 2 (with Android module). Buy I'm facing the error:

> Error:cannot access Retrofit

Other instances like Picasso was injected with success, I just have problems with Retrofit.

My Module

```
@Module
class NetworkModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun providesRetrofit(): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(URL_BASE)
            .build()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun providesPicasso(context: Context): Picasso {
    return Picasso.Builder(context)
            .loggingEnabled(true)
            .build()
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun providesRemoteRepository(retrofit: Retrofit): RemoteRepository = RemoteRepository(retrofit)

@Provides
@Singleton
fun providesRepository(remote: RemoteRepository): Repository = RepositoryImp(remote)

}
```

My Application component

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(
        AppModule::class, NetworkModule::class, AndroidInjectionModule::class, ActivityBuilder::class
))
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(app: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent

    }

    fun inject(application: AppApplication)

}
```

App Component

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesApplicationContext(app: Application): Context = app

}
```

Activity Builder

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(MainActivityModule::class))
    abstract fun bindMainActivity(): MainActivity

}
```

My repository'

```
class RepositoryImp @Inject constructor(val remoteRepository: RemoteRepository) : Repository {

    override fun fetchData() {

    }

}
```

My Remote repository

```
class RemoteRepository @Inject constructor(retrofit: Retrofit) {

    val service: ApiService

    init {
        service = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }

}
```

Gradle Log

```
e: error: cannot access Retrofit
e: 

e:   class file for retrofit2.Retrofit not found
e:   Consult the following stack trace for details.
e:   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for retrofit2.Retrofit not found

w: warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
w: 


e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:138)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:154)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:58)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:103)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:889)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:916)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:888)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:385)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:205)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:166)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:106)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:83)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:377)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:68)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:368)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:133)
    ... 29 more


:app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I found the problem, was in the build.gradle ...
My retrofit instance was in a separate module. This module is a api:

App build.gradle

```
api project(':data')
```

And I was using **implementation** in the retrofit dependencies. I changed to **api** and the problem was fixed.

```
api "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
api "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
```

Comment: Sir, you saved my day!

Comment: Isn't a bad practice to expose your libraries that other layers don't need with api?

Comment: this seems to be an know [Dagger issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/970), another approach could be implement Retrofit in the main module too.

Comment: Modules that don't interact with Retrofit should not know anything about it.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer works but using the `api` function exposes all the other libraries used by the `data` module to the `app` module. To avoid this just add the retrofit dependencies to your app module or where ever you need the dependencies.

```
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
```

Above goes to the `app` module's Gradle file. If your Retrofit instance also has other dependencies such as `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory` do not forget to add these depencies too.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include retrofit dependencies in your **appModule**, you should create a new class which contains the retrofit instance:

```
@Singleton
class RetrofitContainer  {

    val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    companion object {
        private const val BASE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"
    }
}
```

Then, add the following dependencies in your dagger module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object NetworkingModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(): RetrofitContainer = RetrofitContainer()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providePhotoApi(
        retrofitContainer: RetrofitContainer
    ): PhotoApi {
        return retrofitContainer.retrofit.create(PhotoApi::class.java)
    }
}
```