# How to inject data source factory from android pagination library?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-paging, dagger

I'm using pagination library and i want to inject datasource into my viewmodel.
My factory looks like:

```
class ArticleDataSourceFactory @Inject constructor(
    val articleRepository: ArticleRepository
) : DataSource.Factory<Long, Article>() {

    override fun create(): DataSource<Long, Article> {
        return ArticleDateKeyedDataSource(articleRepository)
    }
}
```

My DataSource:

```
class ArticleDateKeyedDataSource(
    private val repository: ArticleRepository
) : ItemKeyedDataSource<Long, Article>() {
    override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<Long>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<Article>) {
        val articles = repository.getInitial(params.requestedInitialKey!!, params.requestedLoadSize)
        callback.onResult(articles)
    }

    override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<Long>, callback: LoadCallback<Article>) {
        val articles = repository.getAfter(params.key, params.requestedLoadSize)
        callback.onResult(articles)
    }

    override fun loadBefore(params: LoadParams<Long>, callback: LoadCallback<Article>) {
        val articles = repository.getBefore(params.key, params.requestedLoadSize)
        callback.onResult(articles)
    }

    override fun getKey(item: Article): Long {
        return item.createdAt
    }
}
```

And my ViewModel:

```
class ArticleFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dataSourceFactory: ArticleDataSourceFactory
) : BaseViewModel() {

    var initialArticlePosition = 0L

    val navigateToArticleDetails: MutableLiveData<SingleEvent<Long>> = MutableLiveData()

    val articlesLiveList: LiveData<PagedList<Article>>
        get() {
            val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPageSize(5)
                .build()

            return LivePagedListBuilder(dataSourceFactory, config)
                .setInitialLoadKey(initialArticlePosition)
                .setFetchExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
                .build()
        }


    fun onArticleSelected(createdAt: Long) {
        navigateToArticleDetails.value = SingleEvent(createdAt)
    }
}
```

After rebuild, i get an error:

```
error: cannot access DataSource
  class file for androidx.paging.DataSource not found
  Consult the following stack trace for details.
```

What does it mean? I have no idea, what i do wrong.
For example, i have no problem to inject repository.

Comment: Your factory code looks fine. can you share dataSource and view model code.

Comment: edited my question

Comment: Sorry i don't know the actual reason. But i guess that you're accessing datasource before initialing dataSourceFactory

Comment: Are you providing the DataSource in your module?

Comment: No. I initialize datasource in create() method in datasource factory. Which described in first snippet. Should i write provider for this factory?

Answer (score 1):

Did you use Android Module? You may need to use `api` dependency in the base module like

```
api "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:$paging_version"
```

And there is similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/47128596/5934119